# Place 2D Bitmap on ARCore anchor Android openGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, arcore

How do you place 2D bitmap on ARCore anchor location that always faces the user (camera)?
I want to place a marker where the user taps.

Do you have to multiply model, view, projection matrices to achieve this?

Currently I tried to use the andy_shadow.obj to display the bitmap since it's a flat 3D object. But I'm having trouble making it face the user(rotating) and placing it where the user taps.

```
Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

This rotates the object to face the camera but when you turn 45 degrees to left/right and place a new one, it will look flat since it is 90degrees from where the frame started.

Maybe placing a 2D object on screen UI in openGL is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 questions you're asking.  First, how do you rotate an object to always look at the camera.

I was able to do this by using the rotation of the frame vs. the rotation of the anchor. in HelloArActivity.onDrawFrame() change

```
planeAttachment.getPose().toMatrix(mAnchorMatrix, 0);
```

to be

```
float translation[] = new float[3];
float rotation[] = new float[4];
planeAttachment.getPose().getTranslation(translation,0);
frame.getPose().getRotationQuaternion(rotation,0);

Pose rotatedPose = new Pose(translation,rotation);
rotatedPose.toMatrix(mAnchorMatrix,0);
```

This will make "Andy" always look at you as you move around.

The second part of drawing a 2D image requires a little more code. At a high level:

1. Create a rectangle using vertices around (0,0,0)
2. Use a UVMap to map the texture on to the quad.
3. Use a vertex shader that multiplies the position by the MVP matrix

A working example is at [QuadRenderer.java](https://gist.github.com/claywilkinson/b1d9c8cbfd6bb48253ead802034e304b#file-quadrenderer-java).  In the sample, uses it just as the ObjectRenderer class is used.